# bind9 behind nginx reverse proxy DoH

Tags: nginx, docker, https, bind

I'm trying to setup `bind9`, in a container, behind a `nginx reverse proxy`.

Basic DNS requests work fine, but I struggle with DoH...

Right now, `dig +https @BASE_URL gnu.org` gives me this error:

```
;; Connection to $IP#443($IP) for gnu.org failed: TLS error.
;; no servers could be reached
```

`curl $BASE_URL`: `curl: (1) Received HTTP/0.9 when not allowed`
`curl --http0.9 $BASE_URL`: timeout.

/etc/nginx/conf.d/bind9.conf

```
server {
    listen      80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name $BASE_URL;

    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen      443 ssl;
    listen [::]:443 ssl;
    server_name $BASE_URL;

    ssl_certificate     /etc/letsencrypt/live/$BASE_URL/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/$BASE_URL/privkey.pem;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://bind9:80;

        proxy_set_header   Host              $host;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For   $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header   Connection        $http_connection;
        proxy_redirect     off;
    }
}
```

/etc/bind/named.conf.options

```
options {
    directory "/var/cache/bind";
    recursion yes;
    allow-recursion { any; };

    listen-on    port 53 { any; };
    listen-on-v6 port 53 { any; };

    listen-on    port 80 tls none http default { any; };
    listen-on-v6 port 80 tls none http default { any; };

    dnssec-validation auto;
};
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM docker.io/debian:12-slim
RUN apt-get update                                \
    && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
        bind9                                     \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
COPY named.conf.options /etc/bind/
VOLUME /var/cache/bind/
EXPOSE 53/tcp 53/udp
RUN chown -R bind:bind \
        /etc/bind/     \
        /var/cache/bind/
CMD ["/usr/sbin/named", "-f", "-d1", "-u", "bind"]
```

Any ideas?
Thanks.